# AngularJS - How to use $routeParams in generating the templateUrl?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Our application has 2-level navigating. We want to use AngularJS `$routeProvider` to dynamically provide templates to an `<ng-view />`. I was thinking of doing something along the lines of this:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/:primaryNav/:secondaryNav', {
        templateUrl: 'resources/angular/templates/nav/'+<<primaryNavHere>>+'/'+<<secondaryNavHere>>+'.html'
    });
}]);
```

I just don't know how to populate the parts within the `<<>>`. I know the  primaryNav and secondaryNav get bound to the $routeParams, but how do I access $routeParams here in order to dynamically serve up the template?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to inject and use the `$routeParams` service (which I would assume would be a better solution) I tried this thinking it might work:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
    config(function ($routeProvider, $routeParams) {
        $routeProvider.when('/:primaryNav/:secondaryNav', {
            templateUrl: 'resources/angular/templates/nav/'+$routeParams.primaryNav+'/'+$routeParams.secondaryNav+'.html'
        });
    });
```

Which yielded this error:

> Unknown provider: $routeParams from myApp

If something like that isn't possible you can change your `templateUrl` to point to a partial HTML file that just has `ng-include` and then set the URL in your controller using `$routeParam`s like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
    config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/:primaryNav/:secondaryNav', {
            templateUrl: 'resources/angular/templates/nav/urlRouter.html',
            controller: 'RouteController'
        });
    });

function RouteController($scope, $routeParams) {
        $scope.templateUrl = 'resources/angular/templates/nav/'+$routeParams.primaryNav+'/'+$routeParams.secondaryNav+'.html';
    }
```

With this as your `urlRouter.html`

```
<div ng-include src="templateUrl"></div>
```

Comment: It would be nice to not have create the one line html file, but I guess it's not too bad. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The problem why the former does not work is documented https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/qNi5lqm-Ps8. As injection targets to `config()` only providers are passed, not actual service instances such as `$routePrams`.

Comment: You actually don't have to create the "one-line html file" - just use the "template:" key instead of "templateUrl" and provide it with a string containing the html one-liner ;-)

Comment: Using this technique, how could the templates fetched from the server side be cached? i.e. the template determined by $scope.templateUrl

Comment: I think the templates are cached by default at least by the browser and possibly by angular as well http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$templateCache. This may help too: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/angular/b3_sbR5iUIU/discussion

Comment: Couldn't you just use `template` instead of `templateUrl`?

Comment: This will actually work, but what about applying a controller for each template selected? Using this method will leave you with only one "master" controller: "RouteController"

Comment: if you set `template` to a function, you can pass `$routeParams` into that function: `$routeProvider.when('/:pNav/:sNav', { template: fn($routeParams) { return $routeParams.pNav + '/' + $routeParams.sNav + '.html' } });`. However, you can't dynamically define a controller this way :(

Answer (score 131):

This very helpful feature is now available starting at version 1.1.2 of AngularJS. It's considered unstable but I have used it (1.1.3) and it works fine.

Basically you can use a function to generate a templateUrl string. The function is passed the route parameters that you can use to build and return the templateUrl string.

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.config(
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {templateUrl:'/home'}).
            when('/users/:user_id', 
                {   
                    controller:UserView, 
                    templateUrl: function(params){ return '/users/view/' + params.user_id; }
                }
            ).
            otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
    }
);
```

Many thanks to https://github.com/lrlopez for the pull request.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1524

Comment: This is now fully supported in 1.2 and it probably the best way: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: what about a dynamic controller based on the params?

Comment: Please, please (please!) tell me that this is possible to do with `controllers`...?

Comment: how do you access the the controller from the template in this case (supplied by $routeProvider)? Normally, if the controller is bound by ng-controller="myController" directive, you can reference it myController as myCtrl. How do I define myCtrl in this case?

Comment: @FlavorScape I just had this issue too - the solution is to do something like $routeProvider.when("/foo", { controller : "FooController", controllerAs : "foo", templateUrl: "foo.html" });

Answer (score 19):

templateUrl can be use as function with returning generated URL. We can manipulate url with passing argument which takes routeParams.

See the example.

```
.when('/:screenName/list',{
    templateUrl: function(params){
         return params.screenName +'/listUI'
    }
})
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 7):

Alright, think I got it...

Little background first:
The reason I needed this was to stick Angular on top of Node Express and have Jade process my partials for me.

So here's whatchya gotta do...
(drink beer and spend 20+ hours on it first!!!)...

When you set up your module, save the `$routeProvider` globally:

```
// app.js:
var routeProvider
    , app = angular.module('Isomorph', ['ngResource']).config(function($routeProvider){

        routeProvider = $routeProvider;
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {templateUrl: '/login', controller: 'AppCtrl'})
            .when('/home', {templateUrl: '/', controller: 'AppCtrl'})
            .when('/login', {templateUrl: '/login', controller: 'AppCtrl'})
            .when('/SAMPLE', {templateUrl: '/SAMPLE', controller: 'SAMPLECtrl'})
            .when('/map', {templateUrl: '/map', controller: 'MapCtrl'})
            .when('/chat', {templateUrl: '/chat', controller: 'ChatCtrl'})
            .when('/blog', {templateUrl: '/blog', controller: 'BlogCtrl'})
            .when('/files', {templateUrl: '/files', controller: 'FilesCtrl'})
            .when('/tasks', {templateUrl: '/tasks', controller: 'TasksCtrl'})
            .when('/tasks/new', {templateUrl: '/tasks/new', controller: 'NewTaskCtrl'})
            .when('/tasks/:id', {templateUrl: '/tasks', controller: 'ViewTaskCtrl'})
            .when('/tasks/:id/edit', {templateUrl: '/tasks', controller: 'EditTaskCtrl'})
            .when('/tasks/:id/delete', {templateUrl: '/tasks', controller: 'DeleteTaskCtrl'})
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});

});

// ctrls.js
...
app.controller('EditTaskCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, $location, $http){

    var idParam = $routeParams.id;
    routeProvider.when('/tasks/:id/edit/', {templateUrl: '/tasks/' + idParam + '/edit'});
    $location.path('/tasks/' + idParam + '/edit/');

});
...
```

That may be more info than what was needed...

- Basically, you'll wanna store your Module's `$routeProvider` var globally, eg as `routeProvider` so that it can be accessed by your Controllers.
- Then you can just use `routeProvider` and create a NEW route (you can't 'RESET a route' / 'REpromise'; you must create a new one), I just added a slash (/) at the end so that it is as semantic as the first.
- Then (inside your Controller), set the `templateUrl` to the view you want to hit.
- Take out the `controller` property of the `.when()` object, lest you get an infinite request loop.
- And finally (still inside the Controller), use `$location.path()` to redirect to the route that was just created.

If you're interested in how to slap an Angular app onto an Express app, you can fork my repo here: https://github.com/cScarlson/isomorph.

And this method also allows for you to keep the AngularJS Bidirectional Data-Bindings in case you want to bind your HTML to your database using WebSockets: otherwise without this method, your Angular data-bindings will just output `{{model.param}}`.

If you clone this at this time, you'll need mongoDB on your machine to run it.

Hope this solves this issue!

Cody

Don't drink your bathwater.

Answer (score 3):

I've added support for this in my fork of angular. It allows you to specify

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/:some/:param/:filled/:url', {
          templateUrl:'/:some/:param/:filled/template.ng.html'
     });
```

https://github.com/jamie-pate/angular.js/commit/dc9be174af2f6e8d55b798209dfb9235f390b934

not sure this will get picked up as it is kind of against the grain for angular, but it is useful to me

Comment: Right on! Havent used it yet but REALLY need it. Are there any other caveats that I should watch out for? Also, any word on Angular implementing it? - I like to use the CDN.

Comment: No idea, I never got the paperwork signed so this a dead end, but you could take the change and try to get it pulled in yourself (I no longer work at the company I was with when I did this, and they didn't pursue angularjs any further)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info and your contribution to the issue - I'll be pulling that and playing around with it in a minute.

Answer (score 3):

Router:-

```
...
.when('/enquiry/:page', {
    template: '<div ng-include src="templateUrl" onload="onLoad()"></div>',
    controller: 'enquiryCtrl'
})
...
```

Controller:-

```
...
// template onload event
$scope.onLoad = function() {
    console.log('onLoad()');
    f_tcalInit();  // or other onload stuff
}

// initialize
$scope.templateUrl = 'ci_index.php/adminctrl/enquiry/'+$routeParams.page;
...
```

I believe it is a weakness in angularjs that $routeParams is NOT visible inside the router. A tiny enhancement would make a world of difference during implementation.

Answer (score 1):

```
//module dependent on ngRoute  
 var app=angular.module("myApp",['ngRoute']);
    //spa-Route Config file
    app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
          $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
          $routeProvider
            .when('/',{template:'HOME'})
            .when('/about/:paramOne/:paramTwo',{template:'ABOUT',controller:'aboutCtrl'})
            .otherwise({template:'Not Found'});
    }
   //aboutUs controller 
    app.controller('aboutCtrl',function($routeParams){
          $scope.paramOnePrint=$routeParams.paramOne;
          $scope.paramTwoPrint=$routeParams.paramTwo;
    });
```

in index.html

```
<a ng-href="#/about/firstParam/secondParam">About</a>
```

firstParam and  secondParam can be anything according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and used `$stateParams` instead of `routeParam`