# AngularJS - Update model based on URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is basically a follow up question this question: [AngularJS - How to use $routeParams in generating the templateUrl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534710/angularjs-how-to-use-routeparams-in-generating-the-templateurl). See my code there for the proper context of this question.

All the navigation part is working great, but now when I navigate, I want to update some properties in my `$scope` based on the `primaryNav` and `secondaryNav`. I thought I could do something with `$watch` but I can't seem to get anything to work. Here are a few things I tried:

```
$scope.$watch($location.path(), function() {...}); //result in js error
$scope.$watch($location, function() {...}); //function runs once on page load, but not after that
$scope.$watch($window.location, function() {...}); //function runs once on page load, but not after that
$scope.$watch(window.location, function() {...}); //function runs once on page load, but not after that
$scope.$watch(window.location.href, function() {...}); //results in js error
```

I could probably create some method in my controller that would take these navs and update everything and navigate off and just add a `ng-click` to all the anchor tags. However, one thing I really liked about AngularJS was being to use real URL-looking values for hrefs (e.g. `<a href="#/priNav/secNav">Foo</a>`). Is it not possible to update my model based on the changing URL when I route without going through some method on the controller? I hope it makes sense what I'm asking.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
 $scope.$watch(function() {
    return $location.path();
 }, function(){
    ...
 });
```

you should pass a function or a string that can be evaluated inside of the scope

Comment: Ahh... I forgot about watching a function. Everything I was trying was on a string. `$scope.$watch($location.path, function(){});` doesn't work, but `$scope.$watch(function() { return $location.path() }, function(){...});` does. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! It works even for [$location.search](http://sharepointkunskap.wordpress.com/2012/11/22/angularjs-sync-location-search-with-an-input-value/)