# How to load language-specific templates in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have a route defined as

$routeProvider.when('/:culture/:gameKey/:gameId/closed', { templateUrl: '/templates/tradingclosed', controller: TradingClosedCtrl });

I would like angular to include the "culture" parameter when requesting the template somehow, so I can serve a translated template.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this correctly you'd like to somehow use the `culture` parameter from the url route to determine which location to retrieve your template.

There may be a better way but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11535887/1207991) describes retrieving the `$routeParams` inside a centralized controller with `ng-include` to dynamically load a view.

Something similar to this:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
    config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/:culture/:gameKey/:gameId/closed', {
            templateUrl: '/templates/nav/urlRouter.html',
            controller: 'RouteController'
        });
    });

function RouteController($scope, $routeParams) {
        $scope.templateUrl = 'templates/tradingclosed/' + $routeParams.culture + '_template.html';
    }
```

With this as your **urlRouter.html**:

```
<div ng-include src="templateUrl"></div>
```

You can define the controller you want to load in your views using ng-controller and access the `$routeParams` for the additional route parameters:

```
<div ng-controller="TradingClosedCtrl">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you :) a shame it's not possible without the include though (saving a resource load and possibly some performance).

Comment: I've chosen to unaccept the answer, because it seems to cause interference with the scope when using the include functionality, so I'm still searching for a good way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I've posted [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053939/how-to-get-localized-templates-templateurl-in-routing-with-angularjs) with working [Plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/3oCumxsJPld4XTE4ZpAQ?p=preview) of solution like @Gloopy suggested.

The reason why you can't implement that without ng-include is that routing is done in 'configuration' block, where you can't inject any values (you can read about these blocks in [Modules documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module), section **Module Loading & Dependencies**

If you want not to introduce new scope, you can replace ng-include with my stripped version of ng-include directive, that do absolutely same that ng-include does, but do not create new scope: [source of rawInclude directive](https://gist.github.com/4387706)

Hope that solution will satisfy your use case.