# Angular $routeProvide when ID goto url with same ID

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How make it Working...

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/show/:id', {templateUrl: '/show/$ID',  controller:'User'}).

    otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

Change **$ID** to **:id**

Comment: Are you saying you have separate *templates* for each ID?

Comment: No... only contents... but content no Angular objects.

Comment: Then why do you want to use the id in the template url?

Comment: Because if it was possible to make my job easier :P

Comment: How? The template URL only loads the template, not the content. If the templates are all the same, you don't need the ID in the template URL.

Comment: So... how to make a call for this url /show/$ID

Comment: You haven't explained what's at that URL. The `templateUrl` is used to load the *template*, not the *content*.

Comment: I think I did not understand the concept. But thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate. View my answer here:
[AngularJS - How to use $routeParams in generating the templateUrl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534710/angularjs-how-to-use-routeparams-in-generating-the-templateurl/15817458#15817458)

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.config(
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {templateUrl:'/home'}).
            when('/users/:user_id', 
                {   
                    controller:UserView, 
                    templateUrl: function(params){ return '/users/view/' + params.user_id; }
                }
            ).
            otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
    }
);
```

Comment: Great!! tnks for Answer! :)