# How i can transmit params from GET into templateUrl in $routeProvider in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, routes

friends.
Can you help me please.

I have angular app. 
How i can add params from GET (in ex :param)

into templateUrl (in ex param -> templateUrl : '/audio/param')
?

```
$routeProvider
.when('/audio/:param', { 
    templateUrl : '/audio/param',
    reloadOnSearch : false 
})
```

If I have url type: http://mysite.com/audio/123
I want templateUrl - /audio/123

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that's possible. The idea behind it is that there is a strict seperation of concerns in AngularJS, which in this case leads to your template and your data being seperated.

You should simply retrieve a template, filled with AngularJS databinding expressions, and do another HTTP request to retrieve the data and bind it to the template through `$scope`. AngularJS is smart enough to cache the template after the first load.

p.s. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thank you! 

Unusual to think in terms of the application.
There is  a website on php. I transfer it to the angular. 
I thought I might can use the existing page of specific audio to upload them as a template.
Continue to develop the use of angular standards.

Answer (score 0):

Related SO discussion about using the new capability in Angular 1.1.3 to specify a function for templateUrl: [AngularJS - How to use $routeParams in generating the templateUrl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534710/angularjs-how-to-use-routeparams-in-generating-the-templateurl)