# templateURL function not getting evaluated correctly

Tags: function, angularjs

I have a route provider defined:

```
$routeProvider.when('/interview', {
    controller: 'Interview',
    templateUrl: function(parms) {
    return parms.target + '/partials/Interview.html';
    }
});
```

But I get the following exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (parms) {
                   return 'partials/Interview.html';
                } has no method 'match'
```

With breakpoints, I found that AngularJS thinks my function is an URL.

Completely confused.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534710/angularjs-how-to-use-routeparams-in-generating-the-templateurl

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using an the stable version (1.0.8) of angular which doesn't allow for `templateUrl` to be a function.  You should give it a shot with the latest release candidate, 1.2-rc3.

#### [1.0.8 documentation for $routeProvider](http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/docs/api/ng.%24routeProvider):

> templateUrl – {string=} – path to an html template that should be used by ngView.

#### [1.2-rc3 documentation for $routeProvider](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/docs/api/ngRoute.%24routeProvider):

> templateUrl – {string=|function()=} – path or function that returns a
>   path to an html template that should be used by ngView.
>
> If templateUrl is a function, it will be called with the following
>   parameters:
>
> {Array.} - route parameters extracted from the current
>   $location.path() by applying the current route