# Getting Variables from URL in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, variables

I see this documentation: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngHref

And this clearly shows that you can manipulate the URL based on values in an input.

But I want to do the opposite. I want to have `http://www.example.com/5` and feed the `5` to a variable I can use in my controller.

How do I do that?

Comment: You can use [__$routeParams__](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$routeParams)

Comment: @Satpal Thanks - but I htink the documentation is somewhat incomplete. Do I really just plug `$routeParams ==> {chapterId:1, sectionId:2, search:'moby'}` into my controller? That seems to not be the full implementation.

Comment: a good example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534710/angularjs-how-to-use-routeparams-in-generating-the-templateurl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $routeParams service to get the ID.

see as an example

```
angular.module('myApp', []).config(function ($routeProvider, $routeParams) {
     $routeProvider.when('/:id', {templateUrl: 'example.html', controller: 'exampleCtrl'});
});
```

And to get the id as a variable user $routeParams in your controller.

```
myApp.controller('exampleCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
    alert($routeParams.id);
});
```

Comment: Sorry I just saw this. I'll try this out and let you know if it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would call a service from my controller, and then assign scope based on the output of that function.

If you already have the values for {chapterId:1, sectionId:2, search:'moby'}, you can either assign them to a shared scope, or cache them in your service, and retrieve them when you call your other controller