# How to use an URL param in a templateUrl using ngRoute?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, ngroute

I am building an angularjs app, my app.js looks like this. However, it throws `Unknown provider: $routeParams` error. Any idea why?

```
var angularSite = angular.module('angularSite', [
  'ui.router',
  'ngRoute',
  'siteController',
  'siteDirectives'
])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$routeParams',
  function($routeProvider,$routeParams) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/Projects', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/projects.html',
        controller: 'ProjectController'
      }).
      when('/Projects/:projectId', {
        template: 'partials/pages/'+$routeParams.projectId+'.html',
        controller: 'ProjectDetailController'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/About'
      });
  }]);
```

Comment: $routeParams is a service and not a provider, what are you trying to accomplish with it in your config method? documentation: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams#!

Comment: I've found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534710/angularjs-how-to-use-routeparams-in-generating-the-templateurl) and I believe it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

[`$routeParams`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) is a service and can **not** be injected in `.config`.

If you want to **set your templateUrl from URL params**, the correct way is to use a function to set the `templateUrl` (as following):

```
.when('/Projects/:projectId', {
    templateUrl: function(params) { // <-- 
        return 'partials/pages/' + params.projectId + '.html'    
    },
    controller: 'ProjectDetailController'
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Available in AngularJS 1.2 access route params at a configuration level replace.

```
template: 'partials/pages/'+$routeParams.projectId+'.html',
```

with:

```
templateUrl: function(params){ return 'partials/pages/' + params.projectId + 'html'; }
```

source - [AngularJS - How to use $routeParams in generating the templateUrl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534710/angularjs-how-to-use-routeparams-in-generating-the-templateurl#answer-15817458)

Answer (score -1):

In the config of an Angular module is not allowed to use services. $routeParams is a Service so you can not use it there.

I would recommend you to include one template or another through your controller **ProjectDetailController**. 
In this controller you can inject and use the service **$routeParams**, in order to choose one template or another. Something like:

So, your config:

```
 when('/Projects/:projectId', {
    template: 'partials/pages/main.html',
    controller: 'ProjectDetailController'
  }).
```

Your controller:

```
Controller.$inject = ['$routeParams'];

/* @ngInject */
function Controller($routeParams) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.template = 'partials/pages/'+$routeParams.projectId+'.html';
}
```

And your main.html template:

```
<ng-include src="vm.template"/>
```