# AngularJS .ng-enter animation doesn't work on first run

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-animation

I'm have a strange problem in my AngularJS app; Animation in my tab-slides switching with ng-include, doesn't work for first time, but works good in second or third time.

Here is my test code on plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/a2x4vkTVgEUEt9mxWaVy/preview

Looks like ng-enter animation class, setting before, template uploads. Please, help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the animation isn't working as your templates are getting loaded out of turn. I recommend either using directives for implementing tabs, or ngRoute.

I have made an example with ngRoute here:
http://embed.plnkr.co/RFw3CZwQmPz9doqe7o1u/preview

I'm not entirely sure what your app is supposed to do, so I may have broken your initial setup.
But I see you're using a lot of rootScope. I recommend using a service for storing shared data between the controllers. Like this (using example from here: [Passing data between controllers in Angular JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js))

```
app.service('productService', function() {
  var productList = [];

  addProduct = function(newObj) {
      productList.push(newObj);
  };
  getProducts = function(){
      return productList;
  };
});
```

**Update:** It is possible to use dynamic templateUrls in the `$routeProvider`, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534710/angularjs-how-to-use-routeparams-in-generating-the-templateurl). This is also possible with the controller. That way you don't have to specify a seperate route for every one of your steps.

Comment: Thx, for your answear. My module is a very big form, 11 steps, ~200 fields, and all for one object "laboratory", so i'm don't want use any services and routes. But you definitely right, when you can it's better use services and routes! :)

Comment: Ah, ok, that is understandable. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thx, again! But in my case there will be more problems from routing :) I'm found solution with $templateCache. Now templates are loading to the app on startup, while user fill first step fields :)

Comment: Yeah, I saw, just thought I could put it there in case others came looking :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i'm found solution for my own question, if you have same problem, you must use a $templateCache service, and here is code on plunker: 
http://embed.plnkr.co/mnB6VwXqHSt6L3IEUvCI/preview