# How send send parameter for $routeProvider in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I want send parameter to templateUrl i want append some numbers after /folder/stockInventoryController.do?param=loadGroupStyles_Controller&fabId=(here I need to add)

```
    myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
        //setup Router for widgets page
        $routeProvider
        .when('/relatedStyle',{
            controller:'groupStylesLoad',
            templateUrl:'/folder/stockInventoryController.do?param=loadGroupStyles_Controller&fabId='+needParameterHere
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`templateUrl` can be used as a function if you need to work some magic on the url. It accepts 1 parameter which takes in the current url.

Looking at your example, there aren't any parameters in `/relatedStyle`; but if there were you'd access and modify them like so:

```
.when('/relatedStyle/:arbitraryParam',{
        controller:'groupStylesLoad',
        templateUrl: function(url) {
            var modifiedParam = url.arbitraryParam++;
            return '/folder/stockInventoryController.do?param=loadGroupStyles_Controller&fabId=' + modifiedParam;
        }
    })
```

Comment: what about HTML part should i add <a href="#/relatedStyle:arbitraryParam">Click Here</a> in the href...?

Comment: No you can do it like #/relatedStyle/arbitraryParam

Comment: The href would match `#/relatedStyle/` and would treat the preceeding section as `arbitraryParam`. e.g. `#/relatedStyle/5`

Answer (score 0):

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534710/angularjs-how-to-use-routeparams-in-generating-the-templateurl
```

see above link ,it may be helpful for u

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways. One is routing

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
        //setup Router for widgets page
        $routeProvider
        .when('/relatedStyle/:fabid',{
            controller:'groupStylesLoad',
            templateUrl:'template/template.html'
        })
    });

myApp.controller("groupStylesLoad", ['$scope', '$routeParams',
     function($scope, $routeParams)
         {var fabId = $routeParams.fabid;}
]);
```

However, if you need to use the query sting.

```
 myApp.controller("groupStylesLoad", ['$scope', '$location',
         function($scope, $location)
             {var fabId = $location.search().fabid;
             // $location.search() returns object like {key1: value1, key2: value2, ...}
        ]);
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Hope this helps.