# Dynamic variable in URL in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular app which has several dynamic fields, each of these fields are changed updated based on config which comes from a backend database.

In order to control what config is used I need to dynamically switch a single variable - I've decided that the URL is the best way to set/switch the variable as there need to be multiple permutations of the site based on the URL so:-

```
/:dynamicVariable/
```

I'm looking for some guidance as to whether this is the best way to do it and what the best way to do it would be? I'm struggling as I don't want to have to set each route for each section like this `/:dynamicVariable/homepage` `/:dynamicVariable/about-us` etc etc. Ideally the core module checks it and sets it but the routing ignores it so `/:dynamicVariable/` becomes the root.

Hope that makes sense, thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534710/angularjs-how-to-use-routeparams-in-generating-the-templateurl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534710/angularjs-how-to-use-routeparams-in-generating-the-templateurl)

Comment: @steur36 although it is similar my issue isn't specifying templates based on dynamic URL variables - it's more to do with setting a base variable from the URL which is then used throughout the app, kind of like a multi-site.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want the dynamicVariable to be?

Comment: @MathewBerg Yes it will be the name of a client, they will have configured the output they'd like in the backend so `/jimscars/` and when you go to the site and `/jimscars/` you will get jims cars logo etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this by using ui.router and nesting states within an abstract parent state which held the client, like so :-

```
.state('rootClient', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '/:client',
            templateUrl: 'app/layout/layout.html',
            controller: 'Layout',
            controllerAs: 'layout',
            noClient: false,
            resolve: {
                client: function ($stateParams, ClientService) {
                    return ClientService.getClient($stateParams.client);
                }
            }
        })
.state('rootClient.home', {
            url: '/homepage',
            views: {
                'content': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/homepage/homepage.html',
                    controller: 'Homepage',
                    controllerAs: 'home'
                }

            }

        });
```

This way all the routes are under the parent route, I also added a resolve to make sure the client exists before moving to the route. Hopefully this will help someone else down the line.

Cheers