# it just keep loading the same page with angular ngRoute?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router, mean-stack

I am learning angular by building a simple bookstore web app using nodejs as a restful api server. I built the server and it works fine, but once it comes to the front end I face an issue. I built the main page using angular ngRoute to get the data from the server and presented as following:

[image: MainPage]

the picture and the title and the description angular read it with no problem but once I press the button "View Details" I should be redirected to a details page using the book id from the server.

From the front End the route provider:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.when('/',{
    controller: 'BooksController',
    templateUrl: 'views/books.html'
})
.when('/books',{
    controller: 'BooksController',
    templateUrl: 'views/books.hrml'
})
.when('/books/details/:id',{
    controller: 'BooksController',
    templateUrl: 'views/book_details.html'
})
.when('/books/add', {
    controller: 'BooksController',
    templateUrl: 'views/add_book.html'
})
.when('/books/edit/:id', {
    controller: 'BooksController',
    templateUrl: 'views/edit_book.html'
})
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
})
});
```

Books Controller:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

myApp.controller('BooksController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 
'$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams){
  console.log('BooksController loaded...');



  $scope.getBooks = function(){
    $http.get('/api/books').then(function(response){
      $scope.books = response.data;
    });
  }

  $scope.getBook = function(){
    var id = $routeParams.id;
    $http.get('/api/books/'+id).then(function(response){
      $scope.book = response.data;
    });
  }


}]);
```

books html where the panel being designed:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-init="getBooks()">
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h3 class="panel-title">Latest Books</h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="row">
      <div ng-repeat="book in books">
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <h4>{{book.title}}</h4>
                  <p>{{book.description}}</p>
                  <a class="btn btn-primary" 
 href="#/books/details/{{book._id}}">View Details</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <img class="thumbnail" src="{{book.image_url}}">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

This the details book html where by clicking the button it must be redirected to:

details_book.html

```
 <div class="panel panel-default" ng-init="getBook()">
 <div class="panel-heading">
<h3 class="panel-title">{{book.title}}</h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div class "row">
    <div class ="col-md-4">
            <img src="{{book.image_url}}">
    </div>
    <div class ="col-md-8">
        <p>{{book.description}}</p>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">Genre: {{book.genre}}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Author: {{book.author}}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Publisher: {{book.publisher}}
</li>


        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and this is the get request from the server to prove the server working find using a certain id

[image: PostMan Get Request]

The error I get once I open the main page:
[image: First Error]

And this error I get once I press the button:
[image: Second Error]

Note: Once I press the button it give me this url:
http://localhost:3000/#!/#%2Fbooks%2Fdetails%2F599701c1f3da51117535b9ab
where the id is 599701c1f3da51117535b9ab which we can see it in the end of the url. But it should give url exactly such as: 
http://localhost:3000/#!/books/details/599701c1f3da51117535b9ab 
and once I write this url manually I get to the page which is the details with no problem but once I press the button from the book.html page I get the previews strange url again which is:
http://localhost:3000/#!/#%2Fbooks%2Fdetails%2F599701c1f3da51117535b9ab
Which load no where.

This is the github url for all the documents: 
https://github.com/AbdallahRizk/BookStore.git

Any suggestions Please!!

Comment: have you checked the dev tools if it has any errors? can you try to replicate your issue on plnkr? it would be easier for us to help you.

Comment: What error you are getting exactly, did you debug and checked whether routeparams.Id has any Id or not?

Comment: its better to have different controller than single controller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL hash-bang (#!/) prefix instead of simple hash (#/) in Angular 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226122/url-hash-bang-prefix-instead-of-simple-hash-in-angular-1-6)

Answer (score 1):

use $rootScope instead of $scope for getBook function

```
$rootScope.getBook = function(){
  var id = $routeParams.id;
    $http.get('/api/books/'+id).then(function(response){
        $scope.book = response.data;
});
    init(getBook);
}
```

Note: add $rootScope to your BookController

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534710/angularjs-how-to-use-routeparams-in-generating-the-templateurl

Comment: Where are you calling that getBook() function

Comment: in the details_book.html

Comment: which is working fine if I type the templateUrl manually but if I press the button I get weird url check in the question the last note I typed

Comment: this link may provide you a solution
https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://blog.hfarazm.com/angularjs-routeparams/&grqid=HBkzEbD8&hl=en-IN

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I have hashprefix !, then my URL should also have ! after hash(#)

```
href="#!/books/details/{{book._id}}"
```

Since Angular 1.6 hashprefix is defaulted to !, you can disable this behavior by setting hashPrefix to ''(blank).

```
.config(['$locationProvider', 
 function($locationProvider) {
 $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}
  ]);
```

Note: This answer from, @Pankaj Parkar at [I get a weird templateURL not as it suppose to give with angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45800718/i-get-a-weird-templateurl-not-as-it-suppose-to-give-with-angular/45801119#45801119)