# Angular giving a weird templateURL

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, angularjs-routing

I am trying to navigate to another page by using the selected objectID.
Angular Routing,

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.when('/',{
    controller: 'BooksController',
    templateUrl: 'views/books.html'
})  
.when('/books/details/:id',{
    controller: 'BooksController',
    templateUrl: 'views/book_details.html'
})   
});
```

Angular Controller:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

myApp.controller('BooksController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams){
  console.log('BooksController loaded...');

 // This To get request all the books: it works fine   
  $scope.getBooks = function(){
    $http.get('/api/books').then(function(response){
      $scope.books = response.data;
    });
  }

   // This to get request a book with specific id it works fine
  $scope.getBook = function(){
    var id = $routeParams.id;
    $http.get('/api/books/'+id).then(function(response){
      $scope.book = response.data;
    });
  }

}]);
```

And then I have this html page which work also fine accept the button in the page, this button supposed to give me a clean templateUrl to navigate to another html page but it give me weird URL:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-init="getBooks()">
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h3 class="panel-title">Latest Books</h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="row">
      <div ng-repeat="book in books">
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <h4>{{book.title}}</h4>
                  <p>{{book.description}}</p>
                  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#/books/details/{{book._id}}">View Details</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <img class="thumbnail" src="{{book.image_url}}">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And once I press the button I'm supposed to get a clean url such as: 
http://localhost:3000/#!/books/details/599701c1f3da51117535b9ab
but instead I get this url!
http://localhost:3000/#!/#%2Fbooks%2Fdetails%2F599701c1f3da51117535b9ab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have hashprefix `!`, then your URL should also have `!` after hash(`#`)

```
href="#!/books/details/{{book._id}}"
```

Since Angular 1.6 `hashprefix` is defaulted to `!`, you can disable this behavior by setting `hashPrefix` to `''`(blank).

```
.config(['$locationProvider', 
  function($locationProvider) {
     $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
  }
]);
```

Comment: thanks mate I struggle with this issue for about 3 hours!!

Comment: @AbdallahRizk pleasure to know that helped, Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Its because your url is getting converted into codes. %2f means a /.

You need to have this configuration to avoid this behavior of angular

```
myApp.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have Prefix in url which is converting into character i.e url encoding.
So you need to fix $locationProvider's `hashPrefix` property by replacing its value with empty/blank string

```
     $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```